# Using react; workflow method for overloading css

Tags: css, reactjs

I am new to the React javascript framework and have a question about styling using CSS.
Using jQuery, my old workflow was to pick an element on the screen, inspect it in Chrome, note the selector/s that triggered the styling, change the element styling in the browser, and then save it to css/sass etc.  If the widget had a hover-state I could make the element visible to see what it looked like.

However using React, and especially for components that someone else has coded, where the component does a 'pop-up' etc, I can't manipulate the DOM to see the component because it is removed from the DOM before I can inspect it.

Now of course I could read the external library code, work out how it works, but CSS inheritance means it would take some time to work out exactly is happening and this seems to be slower than what I was doing before - especially for a simple change.

So my question is, what is the preferred workflow for overloading the CSS for DOM elements that are removed before they can be inspected?

Comment: I also have the same question. I need to set my `foo` to be `true` temporarily to inspect my component in the case `{ foo ? <MyComp /> : null }`. Want to know if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: Install the Chrome react Developer Tools and inspect the shadow Dom.